# How to draw a line using jQuery and HTML5 canvas

Tags: jquery, html, html5-canvas

I have what I feel should be a simple question. I have been trying to search for it for   a while but everything I find is more complex than what I need. So here is my question. How can I draw a simple line on an HTML canvas using jQuery?

```
<canvas id="canvas">
<!-- I want jQuery to draw a line here -->
</canvas>


$(document).ready(function() {
   //I would like the line to draw when the document loads.
});
```

Note.. I am not looking for it to draw or show a drawing motion or anything like that. Basically I just want to be able to load the page and have a line appear. My end goal is eventually draw 3d objects. But before I can do that I first need to know how to do the basics... (IE) Draw a line.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's [how to do it in Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_line) (you can simply insert this inside your function but the script will work fine in a `script` tag without JQuery, and that's probably best). Example:

```
var c=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.lineTo(150,40);
ctx.stroke();
```

If you want to get heavy, it's hard to better the Javascript libraries [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) and [D3](http://d3js.org/).

Answer (score 5):

You don't really need jQuery for this... jQuery provides no canvas functionality.

```
var canvas = $('#canvas_id')[0];
if (canvas.getContext){
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0,0);
  ctx.lineTo(5,140);
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck you could always look at something like [jcanvas](http://calebevans.me/projects/jcanvas/index.php).  YMMV - I haven't used nor really looked through this project.

Comment: Yeah I came across that in my search. I glanced at it. But it didn't look like they were doing anything 3D. Thanks for the info though.